# Firefox stops launching from the dock, but is fine from terminal

Tags: 22.04, firefox, dock

Recently, my Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop installation has developed an issue where after a few hours of uptime Firefox won't launch from the dock icon but does from the terminal.

- Clicking on the dock results in the spinning pointer for several seconds, but nothing else.
- Running `firefox` from the terminal still works, and everything else I have in my dock still launches just fine.
- Logging out and in again fixes it for a while, but it's only a matter of hours before the symptoms return.

How do I resolve this?